# Histogram in matplotlib gets cropped at top

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I have a Python program that generates a histogram using matplotlib.  The problem is that the images that are generated sometimes get cropped at the top.  First, here's the relevant code excerpt, where `plt` is `matplotlib.pyplot` and `fig` is `matplotlib.figure`:

```
plt.hist(grades, bins=min(20, maxScore), range=(0,maxScore), figure=fig.Figure(figsize=(3,2), dpi=150))
plt.xlabel("Raw Score")
plt.ylabel("Count")
plt.title("Raw Score Histogram")
plt.savefig(histogramFile)
```

The problem appears in a situation like the following.  I might have 300 elements in `grades`, 3 of the bins have more than 20 elements in them, and the rest less than 20.  The ones with more than 20 will have their tops cut off and the y-axis will only go up to 20.  This doesn't always happen though:  a different 300 elements in `grades` with a similar distribution might render correctly, with the y-axis scaling to fit within the `figsize`.  Also note that the x-axis always comes out right.

What can I do to get the y-axis to scale correctly and produce bars that fit within the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File a bug report to the matplotlib's developers, and ask them to write a test case on it.

You should be able to set the y axis with the ylim function: is it what you are asking for? Can you show a screenshot of your problem?

Comment: I can, but using `ylim` fixed it; for some reason hist doesn't always set it correctly.  Thanks!